# Read numbers from file until line < n

Tags: linux, bash

As shocked as I am, I can't find this anywhere, and my bash skills are still sub-par.

I have a text file of prime numbers:

> 2\n
>   3\n
>   5\n
>   7\n
>   11\n
>   etc...

I want to pull all primes under 2^32 (4294967296) **plus one additional prime number**, and save these primes to the own text file formatted the same way. Also, my file **has just over 1.3 billion lines** so far, so stopping after the limit would be ideal.

**Update: Problem.**

The bash script has been looping through these 11 numbers for quite some time without me noticing:

> 4232004449
>   4232004479
>   4232004493
>   4232004509
>   4232004527
>   4232004533
>   4232004559
>   4232004589
>   4232004593
>   4232004613
>   004437

What's even weirder is I grepped primes.txt (the original) and "^004437" was nowhere to be found. Is this some kind of limitation of bash?

**Update: Solution**

It appears to be some kind of limitation of something, I really don't know what. I'm re-chosing the perl script as my answer because not only did it work, but it created the ~2GB from nothing in ~80 seconds and included the additional prime. [Go here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33170/bash-scripting-and-large-files-bug-input-with-the-read-builtin-from-a-redirec) for a solution to the bash error.

Comment: does it have to be done in bash?

Comment: I suppose not. I've got no experience in Python if that's what you're suggesting, so it'll need to be a copy/paste. The input file is named "primes.txt". Outputting to a file named "primes2.txt" would be perfectly fine.

Comment: For the problem you have in bash, see this on Unix StackExchange: [Bash scripting and large files (bug): input with the read builtin from a redirection gives unexpected result](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33170/bash-scripting-and-large-files-bug-input-with-the-read-builtin-from-a-redirec)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$  perl -lne 'print; last if $_ > 2**32' < myprimes.txt > myprimes2.txt
```

Gives you the input series of primes up to one prime past 2**32, then stops.  Does not read source file into memory.

Answer (score 3):

In shell, without loading the whole 1.3 billion numbers into memory, you can use:

```
n=4294967296
last=0
while read number
do
    if [ $last -gt $n ]
    then break
    fi
    echo $number
    last=$number
done < primes.txt > primes2.txt
```

You could lose the `last` variable too:

```
n=4294967296
while read number
do
    echo $number
    if [ $number -gt $n ]
    then break
    fi
done < primes.txt > primes2.txt
```

Comment: Your script is giving a weird error now that I've had time to run it for as long as I need to. Read the updated question for more information please.

Comment: If there's going to be a problem, it is likely that the shell stops recognizing numbers at 4294967295; the 4294967296 is triggering overflow.  I'd like to suggest 'change the limit to 2^32-1'.  Since that is not prime (it's a multiple of 5), using the smaller number wouldn't change the result set. Unfortunately, the numbers larger than 2^32 are still likely to cause problems.  At this point, Perl may be the better choice.

Comment: It looks like my bash is good with numbers above 8999999999999999999, but I'm trying the perl one-liner now. I'll reveal the results once it finishes or errors out.

Comment: I found my trace for my test (first script) in the scroll history of a terminal.  I typed the regular text; the computer responded with the italic text.  I know 12 and 45 aren't primes.  The input and output was:
12
_12_
31
_31_
45
_45_
4294967293
_4294967293_
4294967297
_4294967297_
4294967301.  That was formally in a Korn shell on Mac OS X 10.7.5.  Since you ran into problems, I've gone back, created a script, and run it with Bash (3.2 and 4.2) as well a Korn shell; it seemed to work OK in both.  The '32-bit limit' does not appear to be an issue.

Comment: [Just because I'm sure you're be interested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739828/bash-number-limit)

Comment: See this post about the problem in bash with files larger than 2G: [Bash scripting and large files (bug): input with the read builtin from a redirection gives unexpected result](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33170/bash-scripting-and-large-files-bug-input-with-the-read-builtin-from-a-redirec)

Comment: Interesting; 'bug in `bash`' was not one of the possibilities I would have considered.

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy to do in Bash! Just cat the file primes.txt to read it, go through each number, check that the number is less than 2^32, and if it is, append it to primes2.txt.

The exact code is below.

```
#!/bin/bash

n=4294967296; # 2^32

for i in `cat primes.txt`
do
        if [ $i -le $n ]
        then
                echo $i >> primes2.txt;
        fi
done
```

Or you can use this simple Python solution, which does not require loading the entire file into memory.

```
new_primes = open('primes2.txt', 'a')
n = 2**32

[new_primes.write(p) for p in open('primes.txt', 'r') if int(p) < n]
```

Comment: This also attempts to load the entire file into RAM. Do I need to change my IFS or something similar?

Comment: @MisterMelancholy I'll write you a version in Python that reads the file line by line, just give me a few minutes :)

Comment: @MisterMelancholy Added a Python version that doesn't require loading the whole file into RAM, but it looks like Jonathan beat me to the punch with a Bash version that has the same benefit without requiring Python.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing something like this in Perl:

**EDIT**: Hm, it was probably the array that used up all your RAM - this should be more friendly to your resources.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $max_value = ( 2 ** 32);
my $input_file = 'primes.txt';
my $output_file = 'primes2.txt';

open( my $INPUT_FH, '<', $input_file )
    or die "could not open file: $!";

open ( my $OUTPUT_FH, '>', $output_file )
    or die "could not open file: $!";

foreach my $prime ( <$INPUT_FH> ) {
  chomp($prime);
  unless ( $prime >= $max_value ) { print $OUTPUT_FH "$prime","\n"; }
}
```

Comment: This used all of my RAM, and I have 16GB of it. I'm glad I gave myself 6GB of Swap, else I would have crashed.

Comment: @CharlesBoyd Why would you recommend doing this in Perl? More importantly, why did you push all of the primes into an array instead of just appending them to primes2.txt? That could raise the amount of RAM used to double the amount needed to just append the primes to primes2.txt. Finally, Mister Melancholy said he wanted primes _under_ 2^32. Instead, you check that the prime is not _greater_ than 2^32. Thus, primes equal to 2^32 will be appended in your code when they shouldn't be according to the specifications in the question. That is a small bug, but worth mentioning.

Comment: @Maxwell, I thought it would be cleaner to do it in Perl (though actually bash does it nicely) - and I had it storing in an array because I wrote the code snippet (as proof of concept) before it was clear what he wanted to do with it (print it all out to primes2.txt)