# Bash Number Limit?

Tags: linux, bash, numbers

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736745/bash-read-numbers-from-file-until-line-n) earlier that involved pulling large primes from a text file and putting them into another file. It was supposed to grab every prime up to and including the first prime after 2^32, and for some reason this script stopped working.

```
#!/bin/bash
n=4294967296
last=0
while read number
    do
    if [ $last -gt $n ]
    then break
    fi
    echo $number
last=$number
done < primes.txt > primes2.txt
```

It ended up looping through these 11 numbers:

```
4232004449  
4232004479  
4232004493  
4232004509  
4232004527  
4232004533  
4232004559  
4232004589  
4232004593  
4232004613  
004437
```

The original file didn't have `004437` in it, and my bash will handle numbers over `8999999999999999999`

Does anybody have a clue as to why this happened?

> 64-bit Ubuntu 10.04, 16GB RAM, 8-cores @ 3.60 GHz
>   GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

**Update:**

After downloading and compiling the "fixed" bash provided by jfgagne and linking to it in my bash script, it errored out at the same exact spot. Using the significantly faster perl equivalent from my original prime question, I got some file sizes from ls -al:

```
        11  next_prime (just to make sure this was counting bytes accurately)
2147483659  primes2.txt
2147483670  one_too_many
```

2147483659 = 2^31 + 11

The size of the next prime (`4232004631`) is 11 bytes
This holds all primes up to `4232004613`. I also realized that the `004437` is coming from the end of the prime at the bottom of this error loop (`4232004437`). It seems like something is trying to advance, but stuck.

Comment: See this post: [Bash scripting and large files (bug): input with the read builtin from a redirection gives unexpected result](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33170/bash-scripting-and-large-files-bug-input-with-the-read-builtin-from-a-redirec).

Comment: Awesome, I found my first bug in Linux. I'll implement the fix tomorrow. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Actually, it is fixed in a newer version of bash, but not included in all distributions.

Comment: It appears that's not the issue. I downloaded the tar from git, compiled it on my desktop, linked to it in the bash script, and ran it again. I'll update my question in a moment.

Comment: What filesystem type are you running this on?  It looks like your file is stopped around 2GB of space.  FAT32 has a 2GB file limit, so if you are running on a FAT based filesystem, it might not be bash at all, but that you just cannot write any more to the file.

Comment: It was either EXT2 or 4. I had to upgrade my OS, so I no longer have this system, but it was basically a clean Ubuntu 10.4 install with things like vim and gparted installed.

Comment: No, it were enough if you used a newer bash, they have always 64 bit signed integer variables (even on 32 bit architectures).

Answer (score 8):

No, it is independent from the bitsize of your OS. It depends upon a simple declaration deep in the bash sources.

This declaration is __int64_t since around 2002. Since then, bash versions >= 3.00 always use 64bit integer variables, and it doesn't depend on the architecture! It only depends on the bash version.

Previous versions of bash used always 32 bit integer, even on 64 bit OS.