# How to print out large numbers in Bash

Tags: bash

I tried out bc but if i try to find the factorial of number 50 it shows me 1 instead of 30414093201713378043612608166064768844377641568960512000000000000

```
 read T
while ((T--)); do
    read n
    factorial=1

    for ((i = 1; i <= $n; i++)); do
        factorial=$(( i * factorial ))
    done

    echo $factorial
done
```

Comment: The problem is not printing large numbers, it's calculating them.  Bash usually has 64-bit, or smaller, integers ([Bash Number Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739828/bash-number-limit)) so it can't calculate the factorial of 50.  The easiest way to do it in a Bash program is to use an external tool.  One option is Python: `python -sBc "import math; print(math.factorial($n))"`.

Answer (score 3):

With **bc** works fine:

```
    echo "define f (x) {
                if (x <= 1) return (1);
               return (f(x-1) * x);
             }
   f(50) " | bc
```

Comment: `bc` is using a (standard) external tool though... The result of this might differ between `bc` versions (It works for the GNU and OS X ones... It might differ for Solaris, some BSDs, etc...) (`bc` is much faster for this though than `bash`)

Comment: `bc` let's to define function, and in this case is a recursive, it calls to itself until reach 1. The echo sentence send the bc script to bc to be executed

Comment: So  it returns every time the result of the multiplication and it stores it every time in the function and it automatically does the sum after i right bc ?

Comment: yes, more o less is that. When making the first call it is called recursively to the same function. After each call you multiply with the previous value until you reach the first call that makes the sum of F (49) * 50