# Print Fibonacci series using recursion in bash with only 1 variable

Tags: bash, recursion, fibonacci

I'd like to know how to print Fibonacci series using recursion in bash with only 1 variable.

From what I've done:

```
fib()
    {
    i=$1
    if (( $i <= 1 ))
    then echo 0
    elif (( $i == 2 ))
    then echo 1
    else

    echo $(( $(fib $(($i - 1)) ) + $(fib $(($i - 2)) ) ))

fi
 }

echo $(fib $1)
```

I get the correct output of the final iteration, for example if I enter 10 I will get 34, but I'd like to print the whole sequence of numbers, i.e. all the iterations as well. How can I achieve that?

Another way I tried was by:

```
#!/bin/bash
arr[0]=0
arr[1]=1

for (( i=0; i<=10; i++ ))
do
    echo -n "${arr[0]} "
    arr[0]=$((${arr[0]} + ${arr[1]} ))
    arr[1]=$((${arr[0]} - ${arr[1]} ))
done
echo ""
```

But obviously here I've used a for loop, but I don't want to use another variable.

Comment: you have an off-by-one error: fib(1) = 1 not 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for (my kind of) fun, this code prints the Fibonacci numbers from the 0th to the 92nd (as defined in [Fibonacci number - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)) with a recursive function that uses no variables:

```
#! /bin/bash

function fib
{
    echo ${3-0}

    (($1 > 0)) && fib $(($1-1)) ${3-0} $((${2-1}+${3-0}))
}

fib 92
```

Some may claim that using the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, `$3`) for this is cheating, but then other solutions could be said to be using two variables (`$i` and `$1`).

The code takes under 0.01 seconds to run on my (oldish) Linux machine.

The code should work with numbers up to 92 with Bash version 3 or later on any platform.  See [Bash Number Limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13739828/4154375).  Numbers higher than 93 will cause to code to produce garbage results due to arithmetic overflow.

Comment: Thanks alot for you r help appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

Variables in `bash` are global by default. You need to make `i` local explicitly.

```
 fib () {
     local i
     i=$1
     if (( i <= 1 )); then
         echo $i
     else
         echo $(( $(fib $((i-1)) ) + $(fib $((i - 2)) ) ))
     fi
}
```

(Also, your base cases are a little off if you are starting with 0, and 2 need not be a base case; `fib 2` can be derived from the base cases `fib 0` and `fib 1`.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print each fibonacci value from 1 to $n, I suggest:

```
fib_r() {
    local i=$1
    if (( i < 0 )); then
        echo "Error: negative numbers not allowed" >&2
        exit 1

    elif (( i <= 1 )); then
        echo $i

    else
        echo $(( $($FUNCNAME $((i - 1)) ) + $($FUNCNAME $((i - 2)) ) ))
    fi
}

fib() {
    local i
    for (( i = 1; i <= $1; i++ )); do
        fib_r $i
    done
}

fib 10
```

outputs

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
```

It's still one variable, albeit one per function.

I use the bash variable $FUNCNAME in the recursive function so you don't have to hardcode the function name within itself. I got bit by not updating that line when I renamed the function.

---

Of course your performance will **greatly** improve if you cache the results: "fib 16" takes, on my VM, about 3.5 sec without caching and about 0.03 sec with caching.

```
fib_r() {
    local i=$1
    if (( i < 0 )); then
        echo "Error: negative numbers not allowed" >&2
        exit 1

    elif [[ -n ${fib_cache[i]} ]]; then
        echo "${fib_cache[i]}"

    elif (( i <= 1 )); then
        echo $i

    else
        echo $(( $( $FUNCNAME $((i - 1)) ) + $( $FUNCNAME $((i - 2)) ) ))
    fi
}

fib_cache=()

fib() {
    local i
    for ((i=1; i<=$1; i++)); do
        fib_cache[i]=$(fib_r $i)
        echo "${fib_cache[i]}"
    done
}
```